# Access all input/text boxes in td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a table that has a hyperlink with the wording of "Edit" in the last column. In the first two columns are two text boxes with their `readonly` values set to true.

When the user clicks on the "Edit" link I want to change the `readonly` property to false and the wording of the hyperlink to "Save".

After attaching a `click` function to the hyperlink, how do I access the two text boxes? My first thought was to check the `.parent` element for `input` and go from there, but that didn't work. I also tried looking for the `closest` `td` element and doing a `.find` on any `input` but I couldn't get that to work either (although I may be looping through the `inputs` incorrectly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $('.editException').click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Save') {

        } else {
            //Change text of hyperlink (this is working)
            $(this).text('Save');

            //My two attempts at making the text boxes non-readonly
            $(this).parent('input').attr('readonly', false);
            $(this).closest('td').find('input').each(function () {
                this.readOnly = false;
            });
      });
```

Comment: `.parent('input')` makes no sense. `<input>` can't be the parent of anything, because it has no content. Show your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input').attr('readonly', false);
```

You need to go all the way up to the `TR`, because the inputs are in different columns. You don't need `.each()`, because `.attr()` works on all the elements that are selected.